# Facebook Events RSVP

Tags: facebook, events

Is there a way to have someone RSVP to an event by using just a url? An example would be a person logged into Facebook on their phone, then scanning a QR code with their phone on a flyer, and have the qr code contain a url to have them RSVP as attending automatically.

Answer (score 0):

No, but there is an API for this if you have the users authorise your app - see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/ for more information